# Text color doesn't change in Galaxy s6

Tags: android, textview

I use `textColor="@color/red"` attribute for changing color of `TextView`. Text's color changes to Red in Emulator and some phone such as Galaxy s3, ...
But in galaxy S6 color is Black.

I tried using `AppCompatTextView` instead of `TextView`, changing color in Java code But problem doesn't solve.

I use this libraries in gradle file.

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
//    compile 'com.github.QuadFlask:colorpicker:0.0.12'
    compile 'com.amitshekhar.android:android-networking:0.1.0'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'

    compile 'com.thebluealliance:spectrum:0.7.1'

    compile('com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:5.9.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile 'com.l4digital.fastscroll:fastscroll:1.0.1'
```

Why?
What's solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an inline hex color code like **#000000** instead of a reference.

Comment: I think it will not work because also this method doesn't change the color. textview.setTextColor(Color.RED);

Comment: Please try something like this textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));